# python print error

Tags: python, json

**sample.json**

```
{
"datalist": [{
        "element1": "content",
        "element2": "content",
        "element3": "content"
    }, {
        "element1": "content",
        "element2": "content",
        "element3": "content"
    }, {
        "element1": "content",
        "element2": "content",
        "element3": "content"
    }

  ]
}
```

**Python Code**

```
import json

file = "/home/sample.json"

with open(file) as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for elem in data["datalist"]:
  print(elem["element1"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element2"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element3"])
```

**Good Work** Print Result : ***element1 \ element2 \ element3***

But, another **sample.json**

```
{
"datalist": [{
        "element1": "content",
        "element2": "content",
        "element3": "content"
    }, {
        "element1": "content",
        "element3": "content"
    }, {
        "element1": "content",
        "element2": "content",
        "element3": "content"
    }

  ]
}
```

here in second section ; **element2 does not exist**

if element2 does not exist, it gives **KeyError: 'element2'**

```
for elem in data["datalist"]:
  print(elem["element1"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element2"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element3"])
```

printing first section but when it comes second section stop and KeyError: 'element2'

how can fix it ?  thx.

Comment: You can use some if statement checking the length. If the length is 2, you can print element one and element 3. Else print all three elements

Comment: thx, how to? @Bazingaa

i want result : 1.line `element1 \ element2 \ element3` 2.line  `element1 \ (space or blabla) \ element3` 3.line `element1 \ element2 \ element3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries have a `get` method that allows you to return a default value if the key is not found. For example, if `d = { 1: 2, 3: 4 }; v = 10`, `d.get(1, v)` gives `2`, `d.get(5, v)` gives `10`.

So this case you can just give a default value to your code such as `elem.get('element2', '[element2 missing]')` to signify a missing element in the print outputs and the code will run error-free.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options:

- Fix the program, to tolerate missing data
- Fix the data, to be parse-able by the program

## Fixing the program

Instead of:

`print(elem["element1"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element2"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element3"])`

you need to check whether the elements are there:

```
if "element1" in elem.keys() and "element2" in elem.keys() and  "element3" in 
elem.keys():
    print(elem["element1"] + ' \\ ' ...
```

## Fixing the data

Of course, this is easiest: add a key and a value for "element2" in the second dictionary from datalist.

Comment: I worked but it was incomplete and not what I wanted :(
ignoring all element2 ?

if there is no element2, i want to leave it space (" ") instead or write "blabla"

Comment: i want result :
`element1 \ element2 \ element3`
`element1 \ (space or blabla) \ element3`
`element1 \ element2 \ element3`

Answer (score 0):

The *Try* & *Except* Statement Can Be Used:

```
import json

file = 'home/sample.json'

with open(file) as f:
    data = json.load(f)


try:
    for elem in data["datalist"]:
        print(elem["element1"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element2"] + ' \\ ' + elem["element3"])

except KeyError as e:
    print(e, "Does Not Exist")
```

And There Was Some Errors In Your Code